# Is there any English sub for "Ashita e Free Kick"?

Tags: ashita-e-free-kick

I have been finding English subtitle for *Ashita e Free Kick* anime for last two days, and I am unable to find any links or place where I could get it.

Was English sub made for this series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to it's [AnimeNewsNetwork page](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1182) the series hasn't been licensed in English so there aren't any official English subtiltes available either.